# Expected ';' before '(' token error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, compiler-errors

While I was compiling my code , an error has been displayed saying Expected ';' before '(' token. 
Here is my part of code where the error was pointed.

```
@class UITableViewCellEditable;

@protocol UITableViewCellEditableDelegate
- (void)editDidFinish:(NSMutableDictionary *)result //    (in this line of code)
{ 
    [userDataSource setValue:[result objectForKey:@"text"]
               forKey:[result objectForKey:@"key"]];
}
@optional
```

I've tried some possibilities , but still the same error !
how can I deal with it ?

Answer (score 6):

You can't define method in @protocol block. It's only for declaration.